# Tensorflow Datasets "so2sat" dataset only provides black rgb images

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I succesfully downloaded the so2sat LCZ42 dataset with tensorflow datasets. However when sampling rgb images (expected range 0-255) they are all allmost completely black.
Reproduce:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('so2sat', split=['train', 'validation'])
images = []
for i, example in enumerate(train_ds.take(10000)):
  image, label = example["image"], example["label"]
  # only show when perhaps not black
  if image.numpy().max()>150:
    print(i)
    print(image.numpy().max())
    images.append(image)
    plt.imshow(image.numpy())
    plt.show()
```

[This shows allmost entirely black pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNnvN.png)

installed:

```
tensoflow-datasets==1.2.0
tensorflow==2.1.0
matplotlib==3.3.2
numpy==1.19.2
```

This behaviour is unexpected since I expect at least some daytime normal sattelite rgb pictures. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you upgrade tensorflow datasets to `4.0`, tensorflow to `2.4` and try?

Comment: @TFer2 . Your answer is correct. Thanks. The conda distribution of tensorflow datasets is not entirely up to date either so the latest PyPI distribution is required. (this pr is not included in conda: https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/commit/5ae64cfff7473c8757419cff81fd811cf9381a3f#diff-0a9344abf8bc5d205db42f1ae57a45f8cfcabcb4a1be29d4abedd405d3ea430f). Can you state your anwser as answer?

Comment: Sure, Glad i am able to help you.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue can be resolve once you upgrade `Tensorflow Datasets` to `4.0` and `Tensorflow 2.4`.